# Custom Font SVG on webpage

Tags: html, svg

I created an SVG file with custom font:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="70"
     viewBox="0 0 150 70">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: "MyFont";
                src: url("/fonts/MyFont.eot");
                src: url("/fonts/MyFont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
                    url("/fonts/MyFont.woff2") format("woff2"),
                    url("/fonts/MyFont.woff") format("woff"),
                    url("/fonts/MyFont.svg#MyFont") format("svg");
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <text x="0" y="30" fill="black" font-family="MyFont" font-size="30pt">TEST</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

If I open this image in browser everything looks good. But if I put this image to webpage content, browser doesn't use my font. Why? What's wrong?

Comment: If you're using SVG as an image then it needs to be complete in a single file. Embed the font as a data URI.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. But that's not a beautiful solution.  The image - is a logo. Why so differences if I open it as an URL in browser and if it called as a source of the web page?

To minimize size of the logo I have to use data URI only of the smallest font type file (woff2). But are the all browsers an devices supported that format?

Comment: It's like that to preserve userprivacy. Otherwise you could have an image hosted by site A communicate with site B and tell it whenever site A's image was loaded. You could not do this with a raster image so you can't do it with an SVG image.

Comment: I see. Dilemma. Big vector format or small raster format.

Comment: Not really, you only need the letter's T, E and S at the moment. You could create a font with just those letters. That would be pretty small.

Comment: Yea, I also thought about it. Sometimes ago I found a site to do this, but forgot. No problem, will find again. Don't want to install a soft to do this for a single use.